# I wanted to calculate monthly weighted average in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

I have a table that has PIMS code of crudes and first day of the month, its cost(Rs/MT) and quantity Thousand MT to be processed.
I need to calculate the weighted average of cost(Rs/MT) based on PIMS code and for that month only.

In the table, as you can see there are double entries of PIMS code with different quantity and price but with the same date and that difference needs to be considered while doing the average so I want to get a weighted average.

Comment: Have you tried googling for this?

Comment: Yes. The results were not specific to my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work (Assuming your table is called 'Data') 

`Weighted Avg:=
VAR TotalUnits=SUM(Data[Quantity (TMT)])
VAR TotalCost=SUMX(Data,Data[cost(Rs/MT)]*Data[Quantity (TMT)])
RETURN
TotalCost/TotalUnits`

Screenshot below to show examples with some dummy data
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Weighted Average measure using the Quick measure functionality. You can do a basic google search for this as well.

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-quick-measures) for creating a Quick Measure. 
[image: Power BI Quick measure]

Comment: I have already tried this....this formula does't consider monthly weighted average...it does it for the entire data available which is completely wrong...I obviously did a google search and didn't get the required result...

Comment: Please mention in your question that you have tried this and this is not what you're looking for. Also adding a screenshot of what your output should look like would be helpful.